# Ubuntu 12.04.5 wireless connectivity stopped working all of a sudden

Tags: 12.04, networking, wireless, skype, lan

Ubuntu 12.04.5 wireless connectivity stopped working all of a sudden from today morning onwards. I am able to access Skype, but not any website through my wireless carrier. I have tried different routers and via LAN but nothing seems to help. Appreciate any inputs

```
Refer output from wireless-info (http://pastebin.com/RPXJyfLq)
Refer output from lshw (http://pastebin.com/2mSdMJiK)
```

Even if I connect directly to the modem, I am unable to connect via the LAN connection as well.

Comment: Your Wi-Fi works OK according to your output. There may some problem with your ISP.

Comment: There are other machines in my network which work just fine with a similar configuration. The ISP came back and mentioned that I need to get this checked with technical support. What else can I do to check if everything is fine. I tried this on 2 different wireless routers at 2 different locations and I seem to have the same problem. Do you think I should update any wireless drivers

Comment: Appreciate any inputs on this, I am stuck on this for the last 2 days

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-troubleshooting.html

Comment: If I go to the Connection Information section, I see the driver as "ath9k" on the machine where it is not working. But I have a similar machine which shows the driver as "wl". What does this mean? I have attached the output from lshw as well

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I tried the instructions, but that doesnt help